# How to add two dataframes by specifying only some columns for addition

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

**input:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c':['aa','bb','cc'], 'd':[5,9,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,5,6], 'b': [7,8,9], 'c':['dd','ee','ff'], 'd':[50,90,10]})


combinedframes_add = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

**output**:

```
   a   b     c   d
0  5   9  aadd  55
1  7  11  bbee  99
2  9  13  ccff  11
```

But I want my output to like this:

```
   a   b     c   d
0  1   9  aadd  55
1  2  11  bbee  99
2  3  13  ccff  11
```

'a' column should not be added, it should remain the same as in df1.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is remove column `a` from second `DataFrame`:

```
combinedframes_add = df1.add(df2.drop('a', axis=1), fill_value=0)
print (combinedframes_add)
     a   b     c   d
0  1.0   9  aadd  55
1  2.0  11  bbee  99
2  3.0  13  ccff  11
```

Or set `0` to column `a`:

```
combinedframes_add = df1.add(df2.assign(a=0), fill_value=0)
print (combinedframes_add)
   a   b     c   d
0  1   9  aadd  55
1  2  11  bbee  99
2  3  13  ccff  11
```